# How do I pass a Java HashMap to a custom Mule connector?

Tags: java, mule, connector, devkit

Right now the connector code looks like this:

```
// myConnector class
/**
 * Process item
 *
 * {@sample.xml ../../../doc/my-connector.xml.sample myConnector:process}
 *
 * @param binary
 *          the item to process
 * @param stuff
 *          key value pairs for processing
 *
 * @return the status as a string
 *
 * @throws NullPointerException
 *          when one of the parameters are null
 */
@Processor
public String process (  @Payload final byte[] binary,
                        final HashMap<String,String> stuff)
        throws NullPointerException {...}


// myConnector.sample
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(myConnector:process) -->
    <myConnector:process>
            <myConnector:stuff>
                <item1>data1</item1>
                <item2>data2</item2>
            </myConnector:stuff>
    </myConnector:process>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(myConnector:process) —>
```

I have a HashMap stored in a session header inside my Mule flow (#[header:session:myHashMap]), but I can't figure out how to send it to the connector.

--- update ---

If I change the connector sample and the connector element to match I get an error when I built the connector.

```
// myConnector.sample
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(myConnector:process) -->
    <myConnector:process stuff="#[stuff]"/>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(myConnector:process) —>

// my mule flow
<flow>
    <myConnector:process stuff="#[sessionVars.myHashMap]"/>
</flow>

// the error
[ERROR] Error validating example: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'stuff' is not allowed to appear in element 'myConnector:process'. Failing example: <myConnector:process stuff="#[stuff]"/>
[ERROR] error on execute: An error ocurred while the DevKit was generating Java code. Check the logs for further details.
```

Comment: Please show the exact annotations on `process`

Comment: I updated the original post with the method interface and comments.  Is this what you asked for?

Comment: Ah you have a `@Payload` param, always provide all the info please.

Comment: OK please check my updated answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
<myConnector:process>
  <myConnector:stuff ref="#[sessionVars['myHashMap']]" />
</myConnector:process>
```

Comment: If I change the .sample and alter the connector element as you suggested, I get the following error: "[ERROR] Error validating example: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'stuff' is not allowed to appear in element 'myConnector:process'. Failing example: <myConnector:process stuff="#[stuff]"/>
[ERROR] error on execute: An error ocurred while the DevKit was generating Java code. Check the logs for further details.
"

Comment: With some alteration your solution works David.  Thank-you.  Could please update your answer to reflect what worked for me?  Then I'll mark yours as the answer: "<myConnector:process><myConnector:stuff ref="#[sessionVars['myHashMap']]"/></myConnector:process>"

Comment: Updated though I don't understand why `sessionVars.myHashMap` did not work. What Mule version is this?